# How to make SoapClient not connect until call

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

Please advise on this problem. Is it possible to make native php SoapClient to not connect to the host on initialize until some soap method is not called? Or how can I extend it to implement this behavior.

For example what I have now:

```
$this->client=new SoapClient($this->host,$this->params); //now it connects to host to load wsdl
$this->client->Add(123); //it performs some action
$this->client->Remove(123); //performs another
```

What I want:

```
$this->client=new SoapClient($this->host,$this->params); //just initializing do not connect to host
$this->client->Add(123); //it connects to host to load or check cached wsdl and performs some action
$this->client->Remove(123); //again checks wsdl and perfoms action
```

Or:

```
  class Someklass{
    static protected $host=null;
    static protected $params=null;
    static protected $client=null;

   public function __construct() {
       $this->params=array("connect_on_init"=>false);
       $this->client=new SoapClient($this->host,$this->params); // just wraps the model
   }

   public function doSomeAction(){
     $this->client->connect(); //it  actually connects to host and checks wsdl provided
     $action=$this->client->Add(123); //making some action
     return $action;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand what exactly (and why) do you want.  Probably you need something like this kind of wrapper:

```
class someClass extends somethingElse
{
    private $isConnected = false;
    private $soapConnection;
    private $soapHost;
    private $soapParam;

    public soapConnect($host, $param)
    {
        $this->soapHost = $host;
        $this->soapParam = $param;
    }

    private doSoapConnect()
    {
        $this->soapConnection = new SoapClient($this->soapHost, $this->soapParams);
        $this->isConnected = true;
    }

    public wrappedAdd($val)
    {
        if (!$this->isConnected)
            $this->doSoapConnect();
        $this->soapConnection->Add($val);
    }
}
```